# Mysql. Стала появляться ошибка Can't connect to MySQL server on

Tags: mysql

Имеется 3 сервера:

1. БД Mysql;
2. Клиентская часть (сайт);
3. Обслуживает установленные расширения (Высоконагруженный).

Сегодня днем на 2ом сервере (сайте) стала появляться ошибка соединения с сервером БД (`Can't connect to MySQL server on`). При этом третий сервер подключается к бд стабильно!

Я вообще не могу понять в чем дело! Увеличил `max_connection` до 1000, прописал в `iptables` разрешения, все равно 3ий сервер подключается к БД всегда, а 2ой через раз.

Очень нужна помощь, проект на продакшане...

Comment: Все сервера на linux Debian
Настраивал все сам когда-то давно.

Comment: Пинговать пробовали?, пароли логины проверить, мож вирусняк какой в php попап, мало ли, было такое однажды

Comment: Говорю же, подключается время от времени.

делал telnet
Иногда соединяет, иногда нет.

Comment: На машине, на которой проблемы, логи смотрели, системный например. Покачать на нее что нибудь большое, попинговать. У меня одна машина нестабильно работала в сети например из за проблем с сетевухой

Comment: В логах тихо.
Пингуется стабильно без потери пакетов.
Есть подозрения на неисправность железа. Заказал проверку хостеру.

Comment: Хостер проверил железо, все в норме. Перенес базу данных на другой сервер. Переустановил Linux, начал тестить подключение к БД по новой, проблема осталась... Обратился к хостеру, они там разбираются. Жду ответа.